# Trying to check for matches between emails received and google sheet cells (Python)

Tags: python, string, email, google-sheets, compare

Using Python, I'm looking to check for matches of data between incoming emails and cells on google sheets. So far I'm able to print information from both sources in one script. In this example, both sources contain matching info, however when I try to get python to compare both sets of data, no match is found.

Example of the email format it's checking (text is random):

| Ref: 10808123 |
| --- |
| York |
| HCA |
| ASAP |

In the third column of my google sheet are all locations. 'York' is present in the sheet and in the email table above, which I'm wanting the script to find the match for. I've added both sets of information to separate lists in python, and then tried to compare them. Both lists print as 'York' but no match is found. Can someone advise where I'm going wrong? I'll post an update if I figure it out.

I've omitted from showing logins/data locations etc.

This one is driving me a little loopy. I'm quite new to python, so any info is appreciated! See below:

```
import imaplib
import email
import time
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("C\FILE_LOCATION_EXAMPLE", scopes=scopes)
file = gspread.authorize(creds)
workbook = file.open("google_sheet")
sheet = workbook.sheet1

EMAIL_ADDRESS = example
EMAIL_PASSWORD = example
CHECKED_EMAILS = 'example@example.com'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_SERVER)
mail.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
mail.select('Inbox')

sheet_staff_locations = []
sheet_staff_locations.append(sheet.col_values(3))

email_data = []

def email_check():
    mail.select('Inbox')
    result, data = mail.search(None, f'(FROM "{CHECKED_EMAILS}")', 'UNSEEN')
    if result == 'OK':
        for num in data[0].split():
            result, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
            if result =='OK':
                raw_email = data[0][1].decode('utf-8')
                email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
                for part in email_message.walk():
                    if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain" :
                        email_parts = []
                        email_body = part.as_string()
                        split_content = email_body.split('\n')
                        email_parts.append(split_content)
                        print(email_parts)

                        for location in sheet_staff_locations:
                            if sheet_staff_locations in email_parts:
                                email_data.append(location)

                        if sheet_staff_locations in email_data:
                            print("Match found")
                        else:
                            print("fail")

while True:
    email_check()
    print("Checking...")
    time.sleep(5)
    
    answer = input().lower()
    if answer.startswith("e"):
        break

mail.close()
mail.logout()
```

Comment: Can you use `type()` on the contents of your arrays? Just because they both give the same string using `print()` , does not mean the objects are equal. And are you sure there are not leading or trailing spaces in the strings that may be different?